# Variable methods in Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

I wand to check for the existence of a JavaScript method, when I have a variable with that method name inside it.

Using PHP I could do this:

```
$method = 'bar';
$object = new Foo;
if(method_exists($object, $method))
{
    //Foo->bar()
}
```

How can I do this in JavaScript? My first attempt failed:

```
var method = 'bar';
if(typeof(obj.method) != "undefined")
{
    obj.method();
}
else
{
    obj.default();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if the `typeof` the property is `"function"`, using `method` as the key into the `obj` object:

```
((typeof obj[method] === "function") ? obj[method] : obj.default)();
```

Comment: +1 Note there are edge cases where `typeof variable` will say `'function'` when it really isn't.

Comment: Need to change `obj.method` to `obj[method]` (you've got it already for the first use but not the second.

Answer (score 4):

I typically just do `if(obj.method) {...}` but you could always use a try/catch:

```
try {
    obj.method();
} catch(e) {
    // obj or obj.method didn't exist, so let's try plan b
    obj.planB();
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning try/catch as an option which is under-utilized in Javascript.

Comment: But this won't work because `method` is actually a variable that holds the real name of the method.

Answer (score 2):

```
  (obj[method] || obj.default)();
```

would work too, if you want to one-line it.

Answer (score 1):

`['blah']` and `.blah` are equivalent in a Javascript Object, so you can call your method like

```
obj[method]();
```

Where method is a string containing the name of the method to call.

Answer (score 0):

You should the object's *method* property to be **typeof** as **function**.  E.g.

```
 if (typeof(obj[method]) == "function") {
   obj[method]();
 }
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzqrA/2/) explaining how to check for a function.

Comment: This won't work. The problem is `method` is a variable holding the name of the method. Need to say `obj[method]` instead of `obj.method`.